# FormView to refer different data sources in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, label, datasource, formview

I am having a formView in which I have EditItemTemplate.

The FormView will be refering to one datasource(say datasource1) and all the values for the controls in edititemtemplate are Populated from that datasource. Till here it is fine.

I have a label in the same formview, edititemtemplate where it should refer to another datasource(say datasource2). (I want the value to be populated from datasource2). How could I do this?

I am a beginner. Please anyone help!!

Any help is appreaciated!!

Comment: Show your formView markup

Comment: if this two datasource are related each other you can use it's navigation property to  get your value for example your first datasource (table1) has one to many relation with table2 you can write table2.column1 but it related what technology are you use?

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is simply bind that element (label in your case, textbox in mine) to another (in my case) sqlDataSource. So the control would get the data from the sdstbInfo, then when I want to write data back, I use the UpdateParameters of the sqlSomething and do it in the code behind.

in the aspx code say "Title" is from a sql datasource called sdsTbInfo

```
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox id="someUNIQUEid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
.
.
```

Then when you want to get the new data from that same control and pass it to a different datasource....

```
private void onButtonClick()
{
//first find the control you want
TextBox tb = fvForm.FindControl["txtBoxWithNewInfo"];

//then pass it's value to the sql datasources update command
sdsSomething.UpdateParameter("thing").DefaultValue = tb.Text.ToString();
.
.
.
sds.Update();
}
```

Hope this helps